# Line renderer it's overlapping with itself [URP][Unity 2020.3.24f1]

Tags: unity-game-engine

My goal is to combine Bezier and LineRenderer curves to illustrate air flows. The problem that has come up is the following: The LineRenderer overlaps on itself, but not on the rest of LineRenderer. I have tried to modify the ShaderGraph of the material that the LineRenderer has. I have also consulted the options offered by LineRenderer but have not achieved the desired result.

The LineRenderer looks like this:
[image: Airflow overlapping itself]

The ShaderGraph used is as follows:
[image: ShaderGraph]

I don't know if the problem is in the ShaderGraph, in the LineRenderer or in the URP settings. Any clue that could solve the problem?

URP Version: 10.7.0
Unity Version: 2020.3.24f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your screenshot, you're running into issues with your material being transparent. The Linerenderer creates a single mesh. When rendering transparent objects, depth is usually not written to the depth buffer. So when rendering the triangles making up your Linerenderer (which doesn't necessarily happen back to front), your triangles at the back from your point of view may be drawn over the triangles which have already been rendered before.

In your case, given that the arrow itself is opaque, you might simply want to use an opaque material with an alpha cutout. This should render fine.